# 2 Player game is in PSPACE

Tags: time, computer-science, complexity-theory, time-complexity, computation-theory

So I have given a boolean formula Q with 2n variables.Denoted by Q(x1...xn,y1...yn) and it is mentioned that there exists a1....an belonging to{0,1} such that for every b1...bn belonging to {0,1} Q(a1...an,b1,....bn} evaluates to true now the question is to show that this is in PSPACE and U DTIME(2^kn) complexity class.

Now i believe this is just like a two player in which player A has a winning strategy.
and if i can write a program that takes exponential time and polynomial space i will solve it.

now that program should return true if a choice exists for player A ie after he chooses a value for ai from 0 and 1 no matter whatever  bi player B chooses and whatever value 0,1 he gives the formula will always evaluate to true.

So i am thinking on the terms of

```
for ai=a1 to an
{
flag =true;
for j=0 to 1
{
set ai =j;

//check all possible combination of bi's and check the formula
//if formula evaluates to false ,set flag =false and break,
//try the next j for ai;

}

//if flag =false then ai is not a good selection ,select another ai
//if flag =true yes we have a good selection of ai ,
//player 1 will always win in this case
return true and break;

}
```

is this approach correct ,also can i check all the combination of bi's using the same approach

```
for bi=b1 to bn
{
for j=0 to 1
{
//evaluate formula here
//but the problem is i do not have all the values of ai's
// i have only one value of ai ,what will i substitute for the rest
}

}
```

Any suggestion and new approach to tackle this type of problem will be appreciated

Comment: You have not expressed yourself clearly. You presented a claim about a boolean function Q, then said it belongs into a complexity class. What you described isn't a decision problem.

Comment: yes this problem will not take polynomial time thats why we have to show this belong to complexity class DTIME(2^kn) where k>1

Comment: Your reduction is wrong. In a strategy game, the optimal strategy for player A may depend on prior moves of player B. The correct analogy would be if A had a _fixed_ set of "moves" that always wins against all possible moves from B. phrasing the problem in this manner does not make it any easier to solve it though. It's entirely superficial

Comment: also, what is the requirement on k? it is not defined anywhere. The brute force solution solves it by evaluating Q up to 2**2n times, with one 2n-bit counter and one n-bit counter (this shows it's in PSPACE).

Comment: so do you mean if i calculate every combinations of ai's in an upper loop and for every combination of ai i will have to check if there is a combination of bi's that can make the formula false.Can you tell me is that what you meant

Comment: yes that's what i meant

Comment: k can have any value more than one ,its just the definition of complexity class DTIME(2^kn) k>1 i.e all program that runs in O(2^n) or O(2^(2*n)) are in complexity class DTIME(2^kn)

Comment: the time bound requirement is trivial then

Comment: ya so if i  generate all ai's in an upper loop you will require O(2^nk1) time and then i have to again generate all bi's in the inner loop that will also take O(2^nk2) so the overall time taken will be O(2^(k1+k2)) which is in the complexity class DTIME(2^k).Is this right

Answer (score 0):

It's in DTIME(2**2n). Brute force algorithm:

```
//requires n bits space, 2**n iterations of check() or 2**2n time total
loop over all possibilities to choose (a1,...,an):
    if (check(Q, (a1,..., an))):
        return (a1,...,an);

return null

check(Q, (a1,...,an)):
    //requires n bits space, 2**n iterations
    loop over all possibilities to choose (b1,...,bn):
        if (! Q(a1, ..., an, b1, ..., bn)):
             return false
    return true
```